# Table view cells to accept text entry?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm wondering whether I'm going the right direction or not.

I'm trying to build a form in which user will enter data (see screenshot).

I've built a table view but I'm not sure how I can accept data entry from users from there. Haven't found any tutorial on it. Most of them start from a textfield.

Anyone with advices?

[image: Image of user interface layout]

Thanks,

Julien

Comment: Take a look at [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka)

Comment: Thanks, taking a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looking from your UI, having a `tableView` is right. You should be creating a custom `UITableViewCell` that have a `UITextField` as `IBOutlet`.

Something like this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
  @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
}
```

Then implement the `UITableViewDatasource`

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

If needed, you can even have a `configure()` in `CustomTableViewCell` and update the `text` or `placeholder` at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks for the help !